# Increment and decrement value based on rowid in listView using react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am running a sample project. In my project i am using listView. If i am clicking on up-arrow button that the value will be increased and clicking on down-arrow button that the value will be decreased. When i click on any of these two buttons that the value will be changed in all rows in listView. How to change the value in only particular row in listView. Please give me any suggestion.

Here is my code:

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
        dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2}),
         count:1,
      }
    }

incrementFunc(rowID:number, listItems){

        this.setState({
          count : this.state.count + 1
        },()=>{
          this.setState({
       dataSource:new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2}).cloneWithRows(array)
          })
        })
      }
      decrementFunc(rowID:number,listItems){
        this.setState({
          count : this.state.count- 1
        },()=>{
          if(this.state.count <= 1){
            this.setState({
              count : 1
            })
          }
        },()=>{
          this.setState({
     dataSource:new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2}).cloneWithRows(array)
          })
        })
      }
listOfItems(listItems, sectionID:number, rowID:number){
          return(
  <View style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
          <View style={styles.arrowsView}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress ={this.incrementFunc.bind(this, rowID, listItems )}>
          <Image style={styles.arrowStyle} source={require('@images/up-arrow.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>

          </View>
          <View style={styles.numberView}>
          <Text style={{fontSize:15, color:'black'}}>{this.state.count}
            </Text>

          </View>
          <View style={styles.arrowsView}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress ={this.decrementFunc.bind(this, rowID, listItems)}>
          <Image style={styles.arrowStyle} source={require('@images/down-arrow.png')} />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          </View>
)
}
render(){
      return(
<View style={styles.listview}>
        <ListView
             dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
             renderRow={this.listOfItems.bind(this)}/>
        </View>
);
}
}
```

Here is my screenshot:[image]

Comment: Because You have used one state for all items....and you are decrease/inc that state... so it is affecting all.

Comment: What ?   Can you Explain this

Answer (score 1):

`count` state variable is what you are using for all rows which will be the same since its an Integer, consider maintaining a state variable which is an object that will look something like this `{rowId1: count1, rowId2, count2}` `Eg: {1: 15, 2: 10, 3: 20}`

Since your callbacks send `rowId` as argument

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress ={this.incrementFunc.bind(this, rowID, listItems )}>
```

Try setting the state in your `incrementFunc` like this

```
incrementFunc(rowID:number, listItems){
    let count = {...this.state.count}
    count[rowId] = count[rowId] || 0;
    count[rowId] += 1;
    this.setState({ count },
      ()=>{
      this.setState({
   dataSource:new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2}).cloneWithRows(array)
      })
    })
  }
```

decrementFunc can be modified in a similar way.

And then in your `listOfItems` method

```
<Text style={{fontSize:15, color:'black'}}>
   {this.state.count[rowId]}
</Text>
```

Comment: Which method exactly?

Comment: I will modify my increment function like this.

incrementFunc(listItems, rowID:number){
          let count = {...this.state.count}
          count[rowId] = count[rowId] || 0;
          count[rowId] += 1;
          this.setState({ count },
            ()=>{
            this.setState({
         dataSource:new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2}).cloneWithRows(array)
            })
          })
  }

Comment: Just replace `rowId` with `rowID`.

Comment: I am getting this error:
IN this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object. This error is a performance optimization and not spec complaint

Comment: @Nandu Kaldindi Thanks for you reply But I didn't get the result. can you show me the Demo please.I didn't understood your point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to change the specific field in the array, instead of the total count? If you use rowHasChanged function, it has to detect changes only if it occurs.